# IntelliJ caret does not stay at last at the last char of the line

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ Caret does not stay after the last char of the line. It somehow jumps to before the last char or stays at the start of the line

See attached Gif --

[image]

This is so annoying. How do I fix it?

Comment: Does https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/text-direction.html look like the case?

Comment: Thanks @CrazyCoder - I thought so too earlier. But that is left to right

Comment: Might be some system setting, like https://superuser.com/questions/471692/how-to-change-the-text-direction-on-windows.

Comment: Thanks! That too didn't work. I have raised a ticket to Customer support in the meanwhile. 

For now I have reset all the settings -> https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-project-and-ide-settings.html#restore-defaults